# what is the difference between np.random.default_rng().normal(mu, sigma, 1000) and np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)?

Tags: python, numpy

Both seem quite similar in practice, but I was wondering about the difference.

```
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
s = np.random.default_rng().normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
```

Comment: They are equivalent, but new code should use the second form, according to the documentation.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, the two are identical in operation.

There has been recent movement to separate the generation of the random bits from the code that converts the random bits into actual values, such as the Gaussian generated by `normal`.

If you always go through an `rng`, it is easy to change how you generate random bits without making other changes to your code. There are various random number generators of various levels of security out there, and `default_rng(`) uses PCG64.  For higher security work, there are quantum bit generators out there.  For testing, you might want something deterministic and repeatable.